# How to delete list-divider li once delete all of its child li

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I am having jquery mobile listview with data-split-icon "delete". In that list view i am using data-divider to separate the li with different groups. I want to delete the particular data-divider once all li are removed from the listview under that data-divider. Say Example: Check the following listview code snippet.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="d" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="c">
    <li id="group1" data-role="list-divider">Group 1</li>
    <li id="item1">
        <a href="animals.html" data-rel="dialog" class="ui-link-inherit">Cat</a>
        <a id="del_4" data-theme="c"></a>
    </li>
    <li id="item2">
        <a href="animals.html" data-rel="dialog" class="ui-link-inherit">Dog</a>
        <a id="del_5"></a>
    </li>

    <li id="group2" data-role="list-divider">Group 2</li>
    <li id="item1">
        <a href="animals.html" data-rel="dialog" class="ui-link-inherit">Fish</a>
        <a id="del_4" data-theme="c"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the above code, if I delete li "Fish", I want to remove the "Group 2" list-divider li also automatically, since there is no "li" present under this group. I am try to delete separately "li" but i can't remove the list-divider "li" once all the child "li" removed.

Comment: You have duplicate id values which makes finding a solution to this rather tricky. The whole thing would propably be easier if each group would be it's own set of `div>ul` tags with items. That way you can for example then check the length of `li` in each `ul` after removal and then remove the complete group (remove the parent div) ones empty.

Comment: can you give me a sample if you dont mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Get Group id.

```
   var p_id=$(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
```

then check  its child

```
  var childDivs = $("#"p_id li);
```

Remove if it do not contain child.

```
   if(childDivs.length<1)
         $("#"p_id).remove();
```

Comment: hi, when i alert(p_id), it's telling undefined, its not retrieving group id. I am using inside $("[id*=del_]").live("click", function(){
 //alert($(this).attr('id'));
 var p_id=$(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
 alert(p_id);}); Kindly check.

Comment: $(this).parent().attr("id"); alert this what it giving.

Comment: It gives the click list li id, i mean if i delete fish it alerts item1

Comment: okz i see your html code item1 is not in group2 u need put these together by use div or li then code will work fine.

Comment: sorry, i cant understand what your telling to put inside a div/li. Kindly check the above html code which i am having. Tell me how to change that one.